# SACL for shadow copies

Tags: windows, detection, file-access

I'm researching the topic of detecting registry dump from disk shadow copies and realize that I don't see any specific events in the Windows and Sysmon logs.
I tried a simple copy with the command:

`copy \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`

Also tried PoC of the HiveNightmare vulnerability, the logs only show the start of the process, maybe there are some detection options?

Comment: Just checking, did you in fact set the SACL to audit the relevant operations for that file (or, ideally, the directory)? Have you verified that the SACL entry you set creates log entries for non-shadow-copy files when you copy them?

Comment: @CBHacking The system is configured to audit access to several other directories, access to which generates an event with ID 4663, but how to configure such auditing to files inside the shadow copy?

Comment: I think this needs patching from Microsoft's side

Comment: @ganbg Good question. You can do it programmatically using a framework that recognizes \\?\ paths (so, yes Win32/WinAPI, no .NET), or you can try using existing software for it such as `setacl.exe` (https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/), or you might be able to use Powershell's `Set-Acl` cmdlet but Powershell, being .NET-based, doesn't seem to like `\\?\` paths and I'm not sure how to reference shadow copy files via PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, to see the interaction with SAM and SECURITY registry hives, even in a shadow copy, you just need to enable SAM auditing in Group Policy.